# Remove Dollar signs and commas from a string using sed

Tags: regex, sed, expression

sorry if this has been posted in some form already. 
I cannot find anything that exactly answers my question.

Im new to awk, sed, and bash. And I need to figure this out for a class project.

I have a text file separated by commas, with all the data inside double quotes.

Example piece:

```
,"CHADWICK R GORE","C00538975","2012","$10,000.00",,"$10,000.00",,,"$5,000.00",,,"$15,000.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,"$15,000.00","$15,000.00",,,,
```

I need to remove the dollar signs and commas from the fields with money in them.
I used sed to do it.
My sed code:

```
s/"\$\([^,"]*\),/"$\1/g 
s/"\$\([^"]*\)"/\1/g
```

This seems to be wrong, and isn't getting rid of all the commas if there are two in the number.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line does the job:

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS="\"" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^\$[0-9.,]+$/)gsub(/[$,]/,"",$i)}1'
```

the output from your example text is:

```
,"CHADWICK R GORE","C00538975","2012","10000.00",,"10000.00",,,"5000.00",,,"15000.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,"15000.00","15000.00",,,,
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

How would I then use that in my main shell script?

Which looks like this: 
`curl $URL -s | sed -f sedcommands.sed | awk -f myawk.awk`

The myawk.awk script contains code to sum up certain columns and print them at the end.

Comment: the quick&dirty way is pipe your output to my awk line. like `curl...|sed -f ..|awk -f myawk.awk|awk -F '"' .(myline here)` however you could check your `myawk.awk` (if it was written by you), and try to merge my line in it.

Answer (score 0):

[`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr)
easier

```sh
tr -d '$,'
```

`-d` parameter removes those characters

If you must use `sed`

```sh
sed 's/[$,]//g'
```